# How to change this: [ [object1], [object2] ] to this: [ object1, object2 ] in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

controller:

```
$sold_fruits = [];
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    $sold_fruits[] = $client->bought_fruits;
}

$supermarkets = [];
foreach ($sold_fruits as $sold_fruit) {
    // HERE: I want to stop using this [0]
    $supermarkets[] = $sold_fruit[0]->supermarket;
}
```

client model:

```
public function bought_fruits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BoughtFruits::class);
}
```

sold fruits model:

```
public function supermarket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Supermarket::class);
}
```

In the first loop Im getting something like this:
[[obj1],[obj2]]. Thats why I have to use that [0] in there!
Is there any good way to stop using that [0]??

Comment: then use another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal easily by using Laravel collection functions.

Use `flatMap()` when where there is an array of items in a property.
Use `map()` when there is only one item in a property.

**In your case**

There are many bought_fruits for a client, so use `flatMap()`
There is one supermarket for a bought_fruit, so use `map()`

```php
$superMarkets = collect($clients)
                    ->flatMap->bought_fruits
                    ->map->supermarket;
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to put index number in the array like these below.

```
$sold_fruits = [];

foreach($clients as $key => $value){
    $sold_fruits[$key] = $value;
}

$supermarkets = [];

foreach($sold_fruits as $key => $value){
    $supermarkets[$key] = $value;
}
```

---

> NOTE: This is just to answer the question, scroll down more to see the other approach.